# Genre of fonts similar to the Nerve Logo (Jojo Mayer)

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm an amateur graphic designer looking for a genre of fonts, similar to what is being used here in Jojo Mayer's band Nerve's logo:

[image: Nerve logo]

What I'm looking for is extended characters, with a post modern kind of look. I just want to know what these type of fonts are categorized under, so I can try and find a few examples for a project.

Comment: Your time would probably be better spent learning how to draw logos like this yourself, rather than hunting for a font that will do it. Logos like this often don’t even start as a font, they are just drawn from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most applications like this (especially for logos) will be custom drawn and not a ready-made font, although I've seen a lot more fonts like this in recent years. So if your aim is creating a logo I would *highly* recommend not using a font like this but starting with a nice solid font and modifying the shapes yourself.

As for classification and search terms... very broadly, they are *display* and *sans-serif* faces. Other than that there isn't really any set classification so you probably just want to search for descriptive terms. So a search for e.g...

> Futuristic sans-serif display fonts

returns a lot of similar fonts. Two of the top results were:

https://www.behance.net/gallery/15451401/BLANKA-Free-font

[image]

and https://www.behance.net/gallery/33704618/ANURATI-Free-font

[image]